# Documenting PHP classes that use __call()

Tags: php, dynamic, documentation-generation, phpdoc, getter-setter

I was wondering if there is a way to force phpDocumentor to print out the potential methods you could use for getting and setting when you do them dynamically with a `__call()`.

In the case of my simple getter, I would want it to cycle through all private variables and just append `get` to them (and uppercase the first letter, of course).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See the [phpDocumentor](https://www.phpdoc.org/) reference on [`@method`](https://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/method.html).

Comment: Note that using @method (in the class docblock) means you have to **explicitly** write what you want it to show.  So, you'd need to write out all the "potential getXXX()" method names.  There is no "automatic" functionality for populating information into the @method tag.

Comment: Updated link: https://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/method.html